# Access A table synonym created in a DB through a DB Link

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

Problem :-

Table is present in Database 1.

Synonym of the table is created in Database 2 using Db link created in Database2 which is pointing to Database 1.

Another DB Link created in Database 3 pointing to Database 2.

While accessing the Synonym of the table present in Database 2 its giving the error :- 
ORA-00980 synonym translation is no longer valid

So i guess we cannot access a synonym present in a remote database and its object is present in another remote database.

Any suggestions on the above scenario. What would be the best solution for the mentioned problem.

Comment: I can't see why that wouldn't work. Have you checked the synonym is valid from DB2? And how are you accessing the DB2 synonym from DB3, via another synonym or directly? It would pribably help to show all the statements you used, clearly showing which DB and user each was run as.

Comment: Have you checked the synonym is valid from DB2 - Yes the synonym is valid in DB2 ,via another synonym or directly - accessing it directly with a db link which is pointing to DB2 where the synonym is present .. could you please elt me know what exact info u require

Comment: At least the working and failing queries, but ideally also the create synonym and create DB link statements - obfuscating sensitive data but consistently. Basically an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as your description is too vague to pinpoint what is wrong.

Comment: Create synonym and other things are working, even able to access the synonym from the 3rd database using the dblink. but when i am trying to use the table with the db link inside a package i.e select count(1) into var1 <table_name> @dblink it is giving the error while compiling the package.

Comment: created the table table1 in DB1. 

Created a dblink link1 in DB2 with create database link with the connection string (hostname,port,sid) of DB1, 

created a synonym in DB2 as create synonym <table1> for table1@ link1, 

created a dblink in db3 as link2 by giving the connection details of db2 , 

I am able to access the table1 from db3 by using the dblink link2 i.e select count(1) from table1@link2 , 

but when i use the same inside a package its throwing the error  ORA-00980

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems db-link from DB3 to DB1 may help.

See [Ask Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:7095288486502) (notice, below `DB3 <- DB2 <- DB1`, procedure compiled on `DB1`):

> CAUSE
>
> This issue was reported in Bug 2829591  QUERYING FROM A PL/SQL
>   PROCEDURE IN 9I -> 8I-> 7.3.4, GETTING ORA-980. This bug was closed
>   as 'NOT A BUG' for the following reasons
>
> PL/SQL cannot instruct middle database (DB2) to follow the database
>   link during the compilation phase. Therefore in order for this PL/SQL
>   block to compile and run, both database links dblink1 and  dblink2
>   should be defined on the front end database - DB1.  During runtime
>   database link dblink2 will be looked up in DB2 as expected.
>
> SOLUTION
>
> To implement the solution, please execute the following steps:
>
> 1. Create a database link dblink2 on DB1 pointing to DB3
>      ...
> 2. Create and compile the PL/SQL block on DB1.

Comment: Create a database link dblink2 on DB1 pointing to DB3 ...
 The above solution did not allow me to access the table of DB1 from DB3.But when i created a DBlink in DB3 pointing to DB1 which had the same name as the DBlink created in DB2 pointing to DB1 IT WORKED. So oracle lets you hop thorough from one db to anathor DB when your path is thorough a middle layer (or middle DB in this case) when you have the dblink of the middle layer also present in the DB3 the source DB which points to the destination DB which is DB 1